# stackoverflow when cloning graph recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm getting an error *"AddressSanitizer .. stackoverflow in operator new (unsigned long)"* using this version of the code, where I use *copy->neighbors.push_back*

```
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;
    Node() {}
    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
};
unordered_map<Node*, Node*> copies;
Node* cloneGraph(Node* node) {
        if(!node) return node;
        if(copies.find(node)==copies.end()){
            Node *copy = new Node(node->val,{});
            for(auto neighbor:node->neighbors){
                 copy->neighbors.push_back(cloneGraph(neighbor));//stackoverflow 
            }
            copies[node]= copy;
        }
        return copies[node];
}
```

but it works with this version where I use *copies[node]->neighbors.push_back* , why is this happening?
the only difference is using  a reference to an element of global map: *copies[node]*  vs a local pointer *copy*

```
Node* cloneGraph(Node* node) {
        if(!node) return node;
        if(copies.find(node)==copies.end()){
            copies[node] = new Node(node->val,{});
            for(auto neighbor:node->neighbors){
                copies[node]->neighbors.push_back(cloneGraph(neighbor));
            }
        }
        return copies[node];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first implementation, you are creating a new Node each recursive call which is pushed to the stack. Whereas, in your second implementation it is being placed in an array which not part of the local recursion variables(it looks like a global variable), so the stack does not need to keep track of the newly created nodes.

Comment: More accurately, a *pointer* to the node is pushed on the stack (alongside the pointer that is the parameter to the function). The node itself is still allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

When a recursive function causes a stack overflow, one of the first things you should look for is infinite recursion.

Consider a simple graph with two nodes: `A` is a neighbor of `B`, and `B` is a neighbor of `A` (pretty standard for non-directed graphs). What happens when you call `cloneGraph(&A)`?

1. Node `A` is not in the map, so a clone is made.
2. As part of the cloning process, `cloneGraph(&B)` is called.

So what happens next?

3. Node `B` is not in the map, so a clone is made.
4. As part of the cloning process, `cloneGraph(&A)` is called.

OK, back to where we started. This could get ugly if the recursion continues. So the big question is

5. **At this point, is `A` in the map?**

Using the first version of the code, it is not. So the recursion repeats until the stack overflows. Using the second version of the code, it is, so the recursion ends at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version you have a recursion that can produce an infinite loop for a graph with cycles. Note how the condition for entering to a deeper level of the recursion is that a node is not found in the map `copies`, but this map is only updated after the whole recursion finishes.

If your graph is A->B and B->A, then a call to `cloneGraph(&A)` will call `cloneGraph(&B)`, and this will call `cloneGraph(&A)` and so on indefinitely until the call stack doesn't have space for any more.

Answer (score 1):

Think carefully about your algorithm. Presumably your graph has cylces.

As your first version only adds the newly created node to `copies` after recursing into `cloneGraph` the next call will try to clone the same node again, which will recurse etc.